# Local user login on a domain machine, receiving System error 5 occurred Access is denied error

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller, windows-command-prompt

We are trying to use the command prompt **net group** from a local login on a workstation.. This workstation is on the domain, but I'm logging in as the local user: **.\localuser** and not the **domain\user**.

Command prompt we are using.
*net group MYDOMAINGROUP /domain*

I can't get the command prompt above to run on the .\localuser, but I can get it to run on the Domain\User. How can I get this to work on the .\localuser?

The image below is a screenshot and results from the command prompt. The left command prompt is run as a domain user. the command prompt on the right is run as a local user. The local user is getting an **System error 5 occurred Access is denied.**. Does anyone know of any group policy objects or ways to get a local user to successfully request information from the domain controller?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgONz.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with tihs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to allow anonymous/guest users to connect to and read from your domain.  This is a bad and insecure practice.  What you're trying to do is not advised.

However, if you ran the process under the domain-joined computer's system account, it would be able to use the credentials of the computer account to perform an authenticated query of the domain.